# Artifactory is responding randomly slow

Tags: timeout, artifactory, haproxy

I have an HAProxy forwarding the request to Artifactory. Sometimes I have a timeout from the client side, for example requesting some file or just doing a `docker login`.

I was checking the logs in HAProxy and I found the next:

```
Jul 13 06:38:49 artifactory.node haproxy[6288]: xxxx:xxxx [13/Jul/2018:06:38:18.730] front~ back/artifactory01 0/0/0/30440/30440 200 1757 - - ---- 1/1/1/1/0 0/0 "GET /yum/repodata/repomd.xml HTTP/1.1"
```

The values `0/0/0/30440/30440` means

```
Tq ’/’ Tw ’/’ Tc ’/’ Tr ’/’ Tt*

0 Tq: total time in milliseconds spent waiting for the client to send a full HTTP request, not counting data
0 Tw: total time in milliseconds spent waiting in the various queues
0 Tc: total time in milliseconds spent waiting for the connection to establish to the final server, including retries
30440 Tr: total time in milliseconds spent waiting for the server to send a full HTTP response, not counting data
30440 Tt: total time in milliseconds elapsed between the accept and the last close. It covers all possible processings
```

Is 30,440 seconds in response Artifactory.

I was reading the System Requirements, https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/System+Requirements

I increase my instance with 16GB, and in the JVM Heap I increase to 8GB.

```
export JAVA_OPTIONS="-server -Xms8g -Xmx8g -Xss256k -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=\"kill -9 %p\""
```

But still, happen the same, randomly I have this timeout and checking the logs in HAProxy I have this big times response from Artifactory.

Answer (score 0):

To further troubleshoot this you can search the request itself in the request.log in Artifactory.
If indeed you can see that this specific request for some reason took for Artifactory a long time to process, you can start looking whether there might have been a CPU spike at the time or perhaps there was a memory problem.

Take into consideration that each request requires Artifactory to check the DB for data, so the issue might be there or in connectivity between Artifactory and the DB.
So check CPU and memory of the DB server as well (in case you use an external DB).

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answered. I was checking the request.log and the request is accepted and the time in logs is the same and there is no error. I was thinking maybe is a problem of GC, but is a good idea to check the DB.

Comment: Do you any further insight on this issue? Did you resolve it? How did you identify it could be a problem of the GC?